# Visual Studio 2013 crashes whenever I open a solution/project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

Ever since I tried to open a VS2013 solution for a Unity 3D script project and got an "*unsupported project type*" error, I can't open *any* solutions without VS2013 crashing.  I have VS2013 Ultimate.  I can start the IDE without error.  But the instant I try to load a solution it:

- Crashes and tries to auto-restart
- During the restart, crashes again and offers the "Debug/Close Program" option.

These are things I've tried so far to fix the error:

- Rebooted my PC
- Started with the /SAFEMODE flag
- Started with administrator privileges
- Deleted several SUO files

Nothing worked.  I then went into the Uninstall Program module in the Control Panel.  When I right-clicked on VS2013 there wasn't a Repair or Uninstall choice, *only* a **Change** choice.  I clicked on that and oddly it went through the motions of doing the same activity as doing a version update.  The operation took about an hour and had the familiar "Acquiring/Applying" dialog.  After it was done there was a status update saying that the operation succeeded but that the Office Tools module could not be updated.  I then restarted my system.  *I still have the crashing problem*

**Does anyone know how to fix this or what else to try**

EXTRA DETAILS: I checked the system Event Viewer and did see a pair of Application Errors for **DevEnv.exe** for each failure.  The is an Exception in **KERNALBASE.dll**:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.30723.0, time stamp: 0x53cf6f00
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process id: 0x9cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d02a6fbd23f686
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ff3822e0-9662-11e4-bfb1-002618a93a45
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The second is an **Unhandled Exception** from really odd place:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Same here, started today! I am unable to work, any News on this?

Comment: @MarkusWolters The only thing that worked for me was applying VS2013 Update 4.  Something about applying the update made things work again.  I don't know why.  Note, I had Update 3 installed at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've deactivated Web Essentials for 2013 Update 4 (Under Extentensions & Updates), that makes VS load Web Projects again. I have no clue what happened since yesterday, as I did not install any updates.